# Is it possible to obtain values from jax traced arrays with dynamicjaxprtrace level larger than 1 using any of the callback functions?

Tags: python, jax

So I have a program that have multiple functions with its own jax calls and here is the main function:

```
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=("numberOfVoxels",))    
def process_valid_voxels(numberOfVoxels, voxelPositions, voxelLikelihoods, ps, t, M, tmp):
   
    func = lambda tmp_val: process_voxel(tmp_val, voxelPositions, voxelLikelihoods, ps, t, M, tmp)
    ys, likelihoods = jax.vmap(func)(jnp.arange(numberOfVoxels))
   
    return ys, likelihoods
```

This is the output of ys and likelihoods:

```
(Pdb) ys
Traced<ShapedArray(int32[3700,3,1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=3/0)>`
likelihoods
Traced<ShapedArray(float32[3700,7,1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=3/0)>
```

I want to get values from traced arrays ys, likelihoods so that I can modify them. I have tried using the io_callback function:

```
def callback1(x):
    return jax.experimental.io_callback(process_voxel, x , x)
a = callback1(jnp.arange(numberOfVoxels))
```

but the output is the same except for the shape of the array:

```
Traced<ShapedArray(int32[3700])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=3/0)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to one of JAX's FAQs: [How can I convert a tracer to a numpy array?](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-convert-a-jax-tracer-to-a-numpy-array). That answer mentions callbacks, which you use above, but I think you have the wrong mental model of what `io_callback` does.

When you run transformed JAX code, there are essentially two stages of execution:

1. Tracing happens within the Python runtime, using abstract representations of the arrays (tracers) to extract the sequence of operations implied by your code. During tracing in most cases, **array values are not available** by design.
2. Execution happens within the XLA runtime once tracing has encoded the sequence of operations to be run. Array values are available during XLA execution, but **this is not a Python runtime**, and so Python debugging, printing, etc. is not available.

Your question amounts to "How can I access array values from stage 2 by inserting breakpoints into the runtime during stage 1" The answer is: you can't!

But you can use [callbacks](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/external_callbacks.html) and [jax debugging tools](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging/print_breakpoint.html) to encode an instruction to tell XLA to pause execution and pass its values to some callback function during stage 2 execution and let you interact with array values from within Python.

One way to do so might look like this:

```py
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=("numberOfVoxels",))    
def process_valid_voxels(numberOfVoxels, voxelPositions, voxelLikelihoods, ps, t, M, tmp):
    func = lambda tmp_val: process_voxel(tmp_val, voxelPositions, voxelLikelihoods, ps, t, M, tmp)
    ys, likelihoods = jax.vmap(func)(jnp.arange(numberOfVoxels))
    jax.debug.breakpoint()
    return ys, likelihoods
```

This will tell XLA during stage 2 to pause execution, call back to a Python-side debugging tool, and let you interact with the values there.

For more intuition on the mental model of JAX program execution, you may find [How to think in JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html) useful.